# A word or phrase for something thrown away that is repurposed

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What’s a word or short phrase for the following? An object, person, animal or something else that is thrown aside because of its uselessness but picked up by some others and it's being used for the opposite purpose it was meant for.

I can only think of the noun 'frippery', 'kamikaze' or 'a materialistic thing that's irrelevant' but I'm not sure. Thank you!

Comment: Can you think of a word or phrase in your language that means that? English doesn't currently have one, but if you do we might steal it.

Comment: Not really, no. I've learned English my whole life and can barely speak my own language.

Comment: "repurposed junk/trash" would partially fit, but would not imply "opposite" just "different" usage than the original purpose

Comment: How can a *person* be thrown aside and then used for the opposite purpose that it was meant for?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant a situation of some sort. I got it, thanks though! @nnnnnn

Comment: A word or phrase for [salvage] that is repurposed: *salvaged* (colloquially only, no dictionary agrees). "Interesting house; what's it made out of?" - "Salvaged car tires." (whether it's repurposed or not will be evident in the context).

Answer (score 5):

For objects, the term for the process is **upcycling**:

> Upcycling, also known as creative reuse, is the process of transforming by-products, waste materials, useless, or unwanted products into new materials or products of better quality and environmental value.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upcycling)

Note that upcycling has a positive connotation. Depending on your context it might work better to use an adjective: e.g. *upcycled materials*.

Comment: How does that differ from "recycling"?

Comment: @WS2 Recycling doesn’t usually have the stuff end up in a new or better spot than it was before. For example, recycled plastic is no better or worse off than regular plastic. I would say that upcycling is a specific type of recycling.

Comment: The question did not say "a better purpose" but "the opposite purpose", whatever that might mean. If I throw away an old bicycle, what in heaven's name is "its opposite purpose"?

Comment: @WS2 I was confused about that too, and I don’t think many things have an “opposite” purpose, so I just took it to mean a transformative purpose. For example, your old bicycle could be upcycled into a [clothing rack](https://www.welovecycling.com/wide/2015/10/09/creative-ways-to-upcycle-a-bicycle/) or something. In any case, anything is better than the garbage.

Comment: Would you consider a clothing rack, even the rather colourful one shown,  "up" from a bicycle?

Comment: @WS2 It doesn’t matter; it matches the important part of the definition: transforming something unwanted.

Answer (score 1):

**Co-opt** is probably as close as you get in English.

> divert to or use in a role different from the usual or original one.
>   "social scientists were co-opted to work with the development agencies"
>   [Oxford Dictionary online:co-opt](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+co-opt&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+co-opt&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.4242j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

But this lacks the discarded part. Usually, whatever was co-opted was filched, more or less.